# Query objects in an array that match a condition

Tags: mongodb

I have several documents with the following structure,

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": [
      {
        "c": "01",
        "d": "2018-04-16T02:16:55.083Z"
      },
      {
        "c": "15",
        "d": "2018-05-11T13:46:36.052Z"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried `{ 'a.b.c': { "$in" : ["01","02"]} }` to check if the value of c is in that array but doing this uses all the objects in the array, how can I check the value of a.b.c only for the object with the highest date value in a.b.d?

Comment: Store the value of c in date sorted desc order and you can use the query as is.